# How to get a value from a website using html and VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

Here is a screenshot of the webpage I am searching:
[image]

Here is a snippet of the HTML code of that page:
[image]

I want to copy the value highlighted in yellow in the HTML code.

What I know to do in vba-html is to search for buttons and click them.

How can I access the value that is highlighted in yellow? I don't know how to do it because it is outside of a tag.

Comment: if you know how to search and click button, you can simply search the element you want to extract and use `.InnerText` instead of `.Click`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` might be a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

You can use the querySelector method of the HTML Document object to get to the parent element, and then you can use the Children property to get to the second child.  Let's say that the object variable HTMLDoc has been assigned the html document, try...

```
HTMLDoc.querySelector("div.qmod-quote-element-paydate").children(1).innerText
```

Note that the index for the collection of children is 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet you provided, I think you should get the text using `querySelector`, `getElementsByTagName` and `innerText`.

```
Set PayValue = doc.querySelector("div.qmod-quote-element-paydate").getElementsByTagName("div")(2).getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
PayValue.innerText
```